# The CSS fade in picture one by one

Tags: javascript, css, fade

I want to show 3-4 picture one by one. I try to hide the pictures first. When i scroll to somewhere, it will fade in the pictures one by one. But, the question is the second picture will not hide at first, but it will delay to fade in after 1s. What's wrong with the css animation-delay?

```js
 $(window).scroll(function(){
        var body = $("body").scrollTop();
        if (body >= 1000) {
          $("#circle").removeClass("circle_hidden").addClass("circle_display");
          $("#circle1").removeClass("circle_hidden").addClass("circle1_display");
          var classname= $("#circle").attr("class");
          console.log(classname);
        }
      });
```

```css
 .circle_hidden{
        width:50%;
        visibility: hidden;
      }

      .circle_display{
        width:50%;
        animation-name: fadeIn;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        visibility: visible;
      }

      .circle1_display{
        width:50%;
        animation-name: fadeIn;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-delay: 0.5s;
        visibility: visible;


      }
      @keyframes animation {
        0%{transform: translateY(50%);background-color: red}
        100%{tranform:translateY(70%);background-color: blue}
      }
      @keyframes fadeIn {
        0%{opacity: 0}
        100%{opacity:1}
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <div id="bg1" style=" height: 2000px; width: 800px;">
 <p>Topic 1</p>
 <img id="circle" class="circle_hidden" src="images/top7.jpg" >
<img id="circle1" class="circle_hidden" src="images/top8.jpg" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `#circle1` element's opacity is set to 100% during that 500 milliseconds delay.
Adding `opacity: 0%` to the `circle1_display` class seems to fix that but the element is hidden after the animation finishes.

What you can do is to add the delay in JavaScript, for example:

CSS

```
.circle1_display{
    width:50%;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $("#circle1").removeClass("circle_hidden").addClass("circle1_display");
}, 500);
```

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/x3hxrLnm/1/)

Comment: add this setimeout inside the if statement?

Comment: @soul299 Yes and only add the `#circle1` element inside its function, leave `#circle` as it is now.

Comment: add setimeout function into the if statement. It does not work. The same situation.

Comment: @soul299 you've probably haven't removed `animation-delay: 0.5s;` from the `circle1_display` class in the CSS. Also, make sure the animation wasn't run already before starting it.

Comment: yes.... i have not removed animation-delay:0.5s...  so what is the different between animation-delay and coding for delay

Comment: @soul299 I'm not sure but I think that when you add `animation-delay: 0.5s;` in CSS, the element is made visible during that 0.5 seconds delay and if you add the delay in JavaScript, the element's CSS is not changed in any way during the delay.